# Azure Synapse Copy Data Tool conversion overflow error while creating text files in ADLS gen2

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to fetch data (source) from SQL server to create a text file in ADLS (Sink), but I'm facing conversion overflow error. which I found out is with this value (999999999.00000000000000000000). can someone help me on this.
I used Cast function in SQL server to make it an integer value & it did work, but I want to load the values as they are in the source without changing their type. Actually I want to load multiple tables at once.
Screen shot is also attached with. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add your sample input(datatype of value) and expected result for better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment, and I got similar kind of conversion overflow error.

[image]

The cause of error may be ADF is unable to handle the decimal values where **`Precision > 28`** to resolve this the work around is, if possible, make your **`Precision <=28`**

- When I reduced the Precision value from 30 to 28 for my column with decimal datatype it worked.
  [image]
- pipeline worked successfully.
  [image]

**Output**
[image]